# How to access a returned field from a stored procedure by name in C#

Tags: .net, vb.net, stored-procedures

I need to make sure I'm getting the right named field back from a stored procedure and all the examples I'm finding access the reader object by index rather than name. How can I make sure the field I'm getting back from a stored proc is the absolutely correct field.

```
          rdrLogon = myCommand.ExecuteReader()

        If rdrLogon.HasRows Then
            While rdrLogon.Read()
                'userID
                If rdrLogon(0) Is DBNull.Value Then
                    userID = "NULL"
                Else
                    userID = Convert.ToString(rdrLogon(0))
                End If
```

rather than rdrLogon(0) or (1) I'd like to use a name? I've been told to use ExecuteScalar but I cannot find an appropriate example of referencing the field names.
Thanks in advance.

This is a conversion over from classic asp and how they do it is:
           `If Not RS_UserAdd.BOF or Not RS_UserAdd.EOF then
rspCk=(RS_UserAdd.Fields.Item("userCk").Value)
End If`

Comment: I am not sure about your question but you can do `rdrLogon["YourFieldName"]`

Comment: I'm getting "identifier expected" syntax error are you sure?

Comment: Is the schema of the results sets returned by the Stored Procedure non deterministic?

Comment: @Jodrell that concern is legitimate; things can change; for example - someone edits the proc and adds a column in the middle (because it is associated with some related data); or perhaps the query uses `*`, in which case all bets are off. I've even known multi-tenancy environments where the columns are in different orders on different databases, depending on whether the column was retro-fitted to an existing database (where it ends up the last column, obviously), versus created in a vanilla database (where it might go at a more "natural" position)

Comment: @MarcGravell, I agree its more flexible, as long as the column names are not altered. I suppose you could check for known aliases. (In fact, I think I wrote some code like that over a decade ago.)

Comment: I'd like to thank everyone for their help the answer was so obvious I guess I was having one of "those" moments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

options (using C# syntax here):

```
userID = rdrLogon["UserID"];
```

or

```
int colIndex = rdrLogon.GetOrdinal("UserID");
...
userID = rdrLogon.GetString(colIndex);
```

Personally, though, I'd just bind via "dapper":

```
var users = connection.Query<User>(
    "procName", args, commandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
```

dapper always binds by name. Saves you a lot of unnecessary code, too.

Comment: sorry guys its vb.net I have several apps of differing types

Comment: @Lyle feel free to translate it - it'll fundamentally work the same  in VB; in my defense, you tagged the question C# ;p

Comment: are these examples the result of ExecuteNonQuery or ExecuteScalar can you provide more context?

Comment: @Lyle no, they're using `rdrLogon` from your `ExecuteReader` call; if you have multiple rows and/or columns, `ExecuteScalar` won't help you - the question *suggests* there are multiple rows *and* multiple columns. Likewise, `ExecuteNonQuery` won't help you if the sproc *is a query*

Comment: I'm trying to convert this over from classic asp and this is how they do it:      If Not RS_UserAdd.BOF or Not RS_UserAdd.EOF then
rspCk=(RS_UserAdd.Fields.Item("userCk").Value)
End If

Comment: @Lyle then something like: `If rdrLogon.Read() Then userId = Convert.ToString(rdrLogon("userCk")) End If` ?